# HTML Slides Online Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I'm thinking about using HTML5 slides to create an online "Slides viewer/Editor". 
I just use Html5 & Jquery. I just want to make sure that something like this is possible, & would work on mobiles. I saw a lot of Slides Viewers but none of them support editing.
So is already something like this ? & if it's applicable, how long would it take from your point of view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there exists [Impressionist](https://github.com/hsivaramx/Impressionist) a visual editor for the [impress.js framework](https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js) which is THE standard framework for online slides.

so you are not the first to think about this ;-)

Comment: But it doesn't work on Mobile. Do you know anything that works on mobile ?